# Предлагаю разделить метки "орфография" и "дефис"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Сейчас метка [дефис](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81) автоматически заменяется на "орфография" (они объявлены синонимами). Учитывая то, что метка "орфография" просвоена 1,357 вопросам, нам стоит иметь отдельные метки для "подтем". Предлагаю сделать "дефис" независимой меткой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метка [дефис](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81) теперь не связана с меткой [орфография](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f), спасибо за предложение! И простите за запоздавший ответ.